# Import SVG file in Astro and use it without the <img /> tag

Tags: svg, astrojs

Is there a way to use and SVG file in an Astro file directly without using the `<img />` tag. I want something like this:

```js
import Logo from "./logo.svg"
```

and then use it like this:

```js
<Logo />
```

I tried that doing it like that but it didn't work.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can change the import to add `?raw` after the file extension. Then, use `<Fragment set:html={Logo} />` to inline the css. See: [this post](https://ellodave.dev/blog/article/using-svgs-as-astro-components-and-inline-css/) and [the Astro docs](https://docs.astro.build/en/core-concepts/astro-syntax/#fragments--multiple-elements)

Comment: Still works in 01.2024 - astro v4.2.3

Answer (score 11):

You can use code like this without any plugin.

```html
---
import loaderEyes from "svgs/loader-eyes.svg?raw"; 
---
<div class="loader__eyes-container">
  <Fragment set:html={loaderEyes} />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using an npm package called `astro-icon` which I really liked and it solved my problem.

First, I created a folder name icons in src/ and put my icons inside. Then use it like this:

```js
import { Icon } from "astro-icon"

<Icon name="icon_name" />
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: icon_name should be in quotes instead of curly braces. The example given in this answer will throw an error because a variable called icon_name is not defined. astro-icon automatically looks for an "icons" directory and will use the file name as the "icon_name" (no import for the file is needed) so  for `src/icons/foobar.svg` it should be `<Icon name="foobar" />`

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like:

```
---
import { Image } from 'astro:assets';

import firstLogo from '../assets/first-logo.svg';
import secondLogo from '../assets/second-logo.svg';

const logos = [
  {src: awsLogoSVG, alt: "First Logo"},
  {src: secondLogo, alt: "Second Logo"},
];
---

{logos.map(logo => (
    <div>
        <Image src={logo.src} format="svg" alt={logo.alt} loading="lazy" />
    </div>
))}
```

You'll also add image optimization in one go.
Check that you are using the latest version of Astro.

Comment: This is specifically what the poster didn't want. They didn't want to use the <img> tag.

Comment: Thankfully this was specifically what I needed.

Comment: @apfelbox actually, in my answer I use <Image /> that is an astro asset, not <img>

Peace!

Comment: Nice to hear @McNab!

Comment: @dfralan I saw that, however OP was asking about embedding the svg, not about adding it with an image tag. Astro‘s <Image /> tag adds an <img> in the end as well.

Comment: @apfelbox another approach posted, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have used "astro-icon" package. You can see in their docs how to load local svgs in your html.

Basically just:

- Create a icon folder inside src directory.
- Inside src/icons create new svg file. ie. "logo.svg"
- You can now use `<Icon name="logo" />` in astro files to load your svg.

Read more here:
https://github.com/natemoo-re/astro-icon#local-icon-packs

Astro docs on assets:
https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/assets/#move-your-images-to-srcassets

Answer (score -1):

At the request of @apfelbox another approach and more professional one could be:

Create an Icons.ts file where you can store all the icons path you want to use in your project

```
interface IconPaths {
    [key: string]: string;
}

export const icons: IconPaths = {
    star: "M480-229 314-129q-11 7-23 6t-21-8q-9-7-14-17.5t-2-23.5l44-189-147-127q-10-9-12.5-20.5T140-531q4-11 12-18t22-9l194-17 75-178q5-12 15.5-18t21.5-6q11 0 21.5 6t15.5 18l75 178 194 17q14 2 22 9t12 18q4 11 1.5 22.5T809-488L662-361l44 189q3 13-2 23.5T690-131q-9 7-21 8t-23-6L480-229Z",
};
```

Create a Icon.astro component where you can pass custom classes such as fill for example, size and the name of the icon path

```
---
import { icons } from "../../assets/icons";

interface Props {
    name: string;
    size?: string;
    customClass?: string;
}

const { name, size, customClass } = Astro.props;
---

<svg
    class={customClass ? customClass : ""}
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    height={size ? size : "24"}
    width={size ? size : "24"}
    viewBox="0 -960 960 960"><path d={icons[name]}></path>
</svg>
```

And then in your other components use it like:

```
<Icon size="18" name="star" />
```

This approach works perfect with the [Material Icons from Google](https://fonts.google.com/icons) cause they all have single paths.

Just download the Icon, then copy the path content and paste it in the Icons.ts file and assign a name for it. Of course you can modify it to work with multiple paths or with entire SVG as you please.